# MySQL date comparison issue

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I have the date in this format in mySQL databse:

```
2011-02-21 14:40:03
```

But i have to compare only datepart of this dateandtime i.e:

```
2011-02-21
```

How???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution is to use `WHERE col >= '2011-02-21' AND col < '2011-02-22'`, so MySql can use a index if there is one present.

Comment: Yes, because everybody should [write queries for continuous periods as explicit range condition](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates).

Answer (score 3):

```
... where date(datetime_column) = '2011-02-21'
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) is the documentation