# How to select only date from a DATETIME field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table in the MySQL database that is set up with `DATETIME`. I need to `SELECT` in this table only by DATE and excluding the time.

How do I `SELECT` in this table by only date and bypassing the time, even if that specific column is set to `DATETIME`?

#### Example

> Now it is: `2012-01-23 09:24:41`

I need to do a `SELECT` only for this: `2012-01-23`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL date comparison issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229063/mysql-date-comparison-issue)

Answer (score 229):

`SELECT DATE(ColumnName) FROM tablename;`

More on [MySQL DATE() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Comment: I am trying to do this but it does not work $query="SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE date(DateReg='".$date."')";

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE date(DateReg) ='".$date."'"; This should work. Make sure that both dates are of same format, If not format the $date before using in 'where" clause.

Comment: I think you need to be carefull with that because it will not use an index on the ColumnName

Comment: Donot forget to add the Grave accent symbol  ` before and after the column name . In some MySql version it may show the current date.

Answer (score 62):

you can use date_format

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d') from tablename
```

for time zone

```
sql2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(),'US/Central','Asia/Karachi'),'%Y-%m-%d');"
```

Comment: This works perfect because now I can select data from certain days by just having date format '%d'.

Comment: **select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') from tablename** small "y" is not returning year use capital "Y" instead

Answer (score 21):

**Try to use** 

for today:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` where DATE(column_name) = CURDATE()
```

for selected date:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` where DATE(column_name) = DATE('2016-01-14')
```

Comment: This is so simple it makes me feel embarrassed.  I used to check if the datetime value was between yesterday and tomorrow.  But all I need to do is use the DATE() function.  Why didn't I think of this years ago.  Thanks for posting your simple solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `select DATE(time)  from appointment_details` for date only

or

You can use `select TIME(time)  from appointment_details` for time only

Answer (score 12):

In MYSQL we have function called  [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).
In your case your select statement will become like this:-

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateTimeFieldName,"%a%m%Y") as dateFieldName FROM table_name`

For more information about Mysql DATE and TIME functions  [click here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 9):

Please try this answer.

```
SELECT * FROM `Yourtable` WHERE date(`dateField`) = '2018-09-25'
```

Comment: This is the exact one, Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Simply You can do

```
SELECT DATE(date_field) AS date_field FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried doing a `SELECT DATE(ColumnName)`, however this **does not work** for `TIMESTAMP` columns<sup>†</sup> because they are stored in UTC and the UTC date is used instead of converting to the local date. I needed to select rows that were on a specific date in my time zone, so combining my [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419843/811240) with [Balaswamy Vaddeman's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032081/811240), this is what I did:

### If you are storing dates as `DATETIME`

Just do `SELECT DATE(ColumnName)`

### If you are storing dates as `TIMESTAMP`

[Load the time zone data into MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) if you haven't done so already. For Windows servers see the previous link. For Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, and OS X servers you would do:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Then format your query like this:

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`ColumnName`, 'UTC', 'America/New_York'))
```

You can also put this in the `WHERE` part of the query like this (but note that indexes on that column will not work):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`ColumnName`, 'UTC', 'America/New_York')) >= '2015-02-04'
```

(Obviously substitute `America/New_York` for your local time zone.)

---

**†** The only exception to this is if your local time zone is GMT and you don't do daylight savings because your local time is the same as UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Try 
`SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE date(DateReg)=$date` where $date is in yyyy-mm-dd

Alternatively 
`SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE left(DateReg,10)=$date`

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Yo can try this:

```
SELECT CURDATE();
```

If you check the following:

```
SELECT NOW(); SELECT DATE(NOW()); SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

You can see that it takes a long time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table_name where date(datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d') from tablename =>Date only
```

example:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`date_column`,'%d') from `database_name`.`table_name`;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use date_format

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d') from tablename
```

for time zone

```
sql2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(),'US/Central','Asia/Karachi'),'%Y-%m-%d');"
```

You can use select DATE(time)  from appointment_details for date only

```
or

You can use select TIME(time)  from appointment_details for time only
if time column is on timestamp , you will get date value from that timestamp using this query
```

SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) from table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 14) DAY,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

This one can be used to get date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Answer (score 1):

if time column is on timestamp , you will get date value from that timestamp using this query

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of actually putting a working solution to this question:

```
SELECT ... WHERE `myDateColumn` >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Obviously, you could change the NOW() function to any date or variable you want.

Answer (score -1):

I solve this in my VB app with a simple tiny function (one line). Code taken out of a production app. The function looks like this:

> ```
> Public Function MySQLDateTimeVar(inDate As Date, inTime As String) As String
> Return "'" & inDate.ToString(format:="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") & " " & inTime & "'"
> End Function
> ```

Usage:
Let's say I have DateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2 and the user must define a start date and an end date. No matter if the dates are the same. I need to query a DATETIME field using only the DATE. My query string is easily built like this:

```
Dim QueryString As String = "Select * From SOMETABLE Where SOMEDATETIMEFIELD BETWEEN " & MySQLDateTimeVar(DateTimePicker1.Value,"00:00:00") & " AND " & MySQLDateTimeVar(DateTimePicker2.Value,"23:59:59")
```

The function generates the correct MySQL DATETIME syntax for DATETIME fields in the  query and the query returns all records on that DATE (or BETWEEN the DATES) correctly.