# MYSQL Query can select records where inserted date equal to updated date from a datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

before any thing I would like to thank you here is my problem

I want to write MYSQL query that select the records where insert date equal to modified date from a datetime field and ignore the time.

I tried

UPDATE`realty` SET `modifier` = `creator` WHERE `created` = `updated`;

but it worked with the records that was modified in the same time and I want it to ignore the time

Comment: possible dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032047/datetime-mysql-select-only-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

date() cuts time leaving only date

```
UPDATE realty SET `modifier` = `creator` WHERE date(`created`) = date(`updated`);
```

Comment: Thank you dear it worked perfectly more then my way because I I tried ( UPDATE `realty` SET `modifier` = `creator` WHERE `updated` between `created` AND `created` + INTERVAL 23 HOUR )