# Getting all entries from one row and MySQL DATE entry without timezone in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, date

I'm a total beginner in mysql. I have a table with 5 columns. One of the columns is of type DATE. What I want is, read all the columns of one row and from the DATE column read only the date without timezone. How can I achieve this?
I know that selecting all the fields in one row requires query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

And to display only the date from DATE type (the answer I found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032047/datetime-mysql-select-only-date)) is:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d') from tablename
```

Is there a way to merge these queries into one that would do what I want it to do?

EDIT:  This mysql database is integrated into a Node.js server. I wanted to make one query to get all the information from one row with an ID that I have and read the results in Node.js.

This is how I made the table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE requests (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,patient_name TEXT NOT NULL, patient_email TEXT NOT NULL, requested_date DATE NOT NULL,requested_time TIME NOT NULL,status ENUM('submitted','accepted','declined') , PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

When I make this query in Node.js:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id = 4;
```

I get the 4th row, and when I read the 'requested_date' it has the value: 
e.g. Tue Feb 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET). What I want is to read only the date without the "00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)" part.

Comment: Put in an example of your data as it sits in the database, and an example of what you want as a result. That will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all the columns and format the date, you can explicitly list all the columns in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT id , ... , DATE_FORMAT(`requested_date`,'%d') as requested_date_format, ... 
FROM table_name WHERE id=4;
```

Some people prefer this method because it easy to see what columns will be in the result.

OR

You can still use the * method and just add the date at the end.

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`requested_date`,'%d') as requested_date_format
FROM table_name WHERE id=4;
```

Then you will get all the columns plus the formatted date. Note that the requested_date column will appear twice (kind of), but the formatted date will be in the column: `requested_date_format`.