# MYSQL returns full datetime string on SELECT query when column type is DATE

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, datetime

I have a hard time finding answer to my question after many researches on google, but my terms do not seem accurate enough to yield the correct answers to my question.

I have a database storing information on customers: first name, last name, birthdate etc.

The problem is specific to my birthdate column. The type is set to DATE and for every results, everything shows up as a DATE in phpmyadmin, but when I use SELECT in my script to retrieve rows, the birthdate column is returned like if it was DATETIME type except when the value is 0000-00-00.

I am using node-mysql to retrieve results from mysql table in my app. I built a module on top of node-mysql to shorten required code for pooling, which is where DatabasePool function comes from. Here is a sample node.js code from which the behaviour is shown:

```
property: {
    get: function(id, callback) {
        mysql.DatabasePool(function() {
            this.query('SELECT birthdate FROM ICM_Contact WHERE ICM_contact_id = ? LIMIT 1', [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log(rows[0]);
                callback(null, ICM.contact.revive(rows[0]));
            })
        });
    }
}
```

For given date: 2015-08-11 it will return `{ birthdate: Tue Aug 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) }`, but for date 0000-00-00 it will return `{ birthdate: '0000-00-00' }` as expected.

I don't have any clue why phpmyadmin displays the date correctly no matter what, but when I do the query from my script, it won't return the date correctly.

I have tried the following: [datetime mySQL SELECT only date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032047/datetime-mysql-select-only-date)

```
property: {
    get: function(id, callback) {
        mysql.DatabasePool(function() {
            this.query('SELECT date(birthdate) FROM ICM_Contact WHERE ICM_contact_id = ? LIMIT 1', [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log(rows[0]);
                callback(null, ICM.contact.revive(rows[0]));
            })
        });
    }
}
```

But still the date is returned as datetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
property: {
    get: function(id, callback) {
        mysql.DatabasePool(function() {
            this.query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(birthdate,\'%m-%d-%Y\') FROM ICM_Contact WHERE ICM_contact_id = ? LIMIT 1', [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log(rows[0]);
                callback(null, ICM.contact.revive(rows[0]));
            })
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that the value returned by node mysql seems to be a javascript date object which explains why the date is returned as datetime, where phpmyadmin returns only the date.

Comment: Well, I think when you store dates in a database, they are automatically saved in UTC time, it means "Wed Jul 23 2014 12:31:00 GMT+0000" for example. That why you need to convert date/time to string type then return it to client.

Comment: If you failed to run, try to change from "'%m-%d-%Y'" to '"%m-%d-%Y"'

Comment: Possible, but as phpmyadmin was not yielding this behaviour, I decided to check the returned row type in node.js and it returned a date object, like if node-mysql was converting all date-like types to date objects.

Comment: Well, I backslashed like this `'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(birthdate,\'%m-%d-%Y\') FROM ICM_Contact WHERE ICM_contact_id = ? LIMIT 1'`

Answer (score 26):

The reason why the full datetime is returned instead of just the date is that the node mysql module casts all mysql date / datetime data types into JavaScript Date objects. Alternative to the accepted solution, this feature can be turned off by setting `dateStrings` to `true` in the connections:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydb',
    port: '3306',
    ...
    dateStrings: true
});
```