# How to select a date and ignor the time

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I made a SQL Statement and I want to use the date but without the time.

My Select is:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dw, [Order].PerformDate)
```

And my Group by is:

```
GROUP BY [Order].PerformDate
```

Now how can I ignore the time?

Comment: see **[mysql date()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp)** function

Comment: duplicate of [datetime-mysql-select-only-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032047/datetime-mysql-select-only-date)

Comment: I don't think that `datepart` is  a MySQL function. Are you sure it is MySQL with `datapart` you are using?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: It seems that the OP use sql server , correct me if i'm wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT` function of SQL

```
select datepart(dw, CONVERT(DATE,[Order].PerformDate)) 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,[Order].PerformDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast datetime value to date:

```
select cast(`Order`.PerformDate as date) as PerformDate
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY says "I want one result row per ____". In your case one row per PerformDate. If PerformDate is a datetime, but you only want to have one result row per date without time, then you must extract the date part:

```
group by cast(performdate as date)
```

You also want to display the weekday with `datepart(dw, performdate)` but this is no longer possible, because PerformDate is no longer available. Only its date part is. So:

```
select datepart(dw, cast(performdate as date))
from ...
group by cast(performdate as date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one method:

```
select date_format(`order`.PerformDate, '%Y%m%d')
...
group by 1
```